# Google calendar push notifications do not notify on delete

Tags: php, api, push-notification, google-calendar-api

I have registered push notifications. Updates and creations work just fine, but I am not able to receive deleted events.

I am setting the channel like this

```
    public function setUpPushNotificationsChannel($lengthHours = 168){
        $this->cancelPushNotificationsChannel();
        $channel = new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel();
        $channel->setId(create_guid());
        $channel->setType('web_hook');
        $channel->setAddress( $this->url);
        $channel->setToken(Utils::encrypt($this->pushSecret);
        $dateTime = new DateTime();
        $dateTime->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string("$lengthHours hours"));
        //timestamp is in milliseconds for google -.-
        $channel->setExpiration($dateTime->getTimestamp() * 1000);
        //this does not do anything
        $optParams = array(
            'singleEvents' => true,
            'showDeleted' =>true,
        );
        $channel = $this->service->events->watch($this->getGoogleCalendarId(),$channel,$optParams);
        $this->gcalendarSetting->gcalendar_push_channel_id_c = $channel->getId();
        $this->gcalendarSetting->gcalendar_resource_id_c = $channel->getResourceId();
        $this->gcalendarSetting->save();
    }
```

I could not find anything in the google doc, maybe I am missing some parameter for deleted events?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that the problem is not in deleted events, but in everything. The notifications just quite often don't arrive and I just had bad luck while I was testing it. It seems that almost 50% of changes are not pushed, which is quite unsatisfying.